# Does Cell Factory supports two different types of objects?

Tags: javafx

I'm populating my ListView with two different types of objects, and I would like to rename all the items inside the ListView. I'm using the following code to rename all the cells that containing items from a specific kind of object.

```
public void listViewSetCellFactory() {
    listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Banana>() {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(Banana item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                String text = item.getBananaName();
                setText(text);

            }
        }
    });
}
```

But since my ListView contains two different types ob objects (Bananas and Grapefruits). How can I rename the cells that contains grapefruits too using the same event?

Comment: Sorry, I had to change the name of the variables to post my question here. I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to move the method returning the name to a supertype and using the same method for all names. To include the type name in the property name just results in longer identifiers without any additional benefit (`banana.getName()` would be just as easy to understand as `banana.getBananaName()`, maybe even better).

This would allow you to create a `ListView<Fruit>` and treat the items the same way:

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Fruit>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Fruit item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setText(empty ? null : item.getName());
    }
});
```

If you cannot do this you've got to swallow the bitter pill and use `instanceof` to determine the type of the item and treat the element accordingly:

```
listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        String text;
        if (empty) {
            text = null;
        } else if (item instanceof Banana) {
            text = ((Banana) item).getBananaName();
        } else {
            text = ((Grapefruit) item).getGrapefruitName();
        }

        setText(text);
    }
});
```